# How to write an Elasticsearch query that aggregates by a field, and for each one of another field?

Tags: elasticsearch, graph, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

Given an index with documents of the following format

```
{
    "userA": "user1",
    "relation": 10,
    "userB": "user2"
}
```

How to create an aggregation query that will display for each user (from a given list), the sum of 'relation's between them.
for example: given `userX, userY`
result will be:

```
{
    user4: {user1: 100, user2: 300, user3: 350},
    ...
    userX: {user4: 123, user5: 456}
}
```

I tried to do it using 2 separate queries like that (the second one with userB instead in the aggs field)

```
GET myindex*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "userA": [<input user ids>]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "userB": [<input user ids>]
          }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "connections": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userA" //// Second query with `userB`
      },
      "aggs": {
        "privateConversationCount": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "privateConversationCount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this is not correct, it requires a nested aggregation.
How could I write a query that will answer that need?

Comment: Example in question is not clear. Please paste more sample data and what is expected. you mentioned "for example: given user4, user5 result will be" but then result doesn't contain user5.

Comment: @SachinDangol thanks, done. Changed to userX and userY. It doesn't really matter, it's just that given 2 users, the query should return all other users each one has a relation with